# Query Firestore collection with OR operator with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to filter my data with conditions of `you are participant or the room is public`

```dart
// get list of rooms contains your Uid
var participantSnapshot = _roomCollection.where('participants', arrayContains: 'userUid');
// get list of public room
var publicRoomSnapshot = _roomCollection.where('private', isEqualTo: false);
```

How can I implement this query in Flutter/Dart?

Comment: Is this a stream call or a future call?

Comment: It's a stream call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to merge your two APIs into one. There are a couple of ways to use it.

1. Create two methods for your queries.

```dart
      Stream<List<RoomModel>> stream1(String userUid) {
        var ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('rooms')
            .where('participants', arrayContains: userUid);
    
        return ref
            .snapshots()
            .map((list) => list.docs.map((doc) => RoomModel.fromForestore(doc)).toList());
      }
    
      Stream<List<RoomModel>> stream2() {
        var ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('rooms')
            .where('private', isEqualTo: false);
    
        return ref
            .snapshots()
            .map((list) => list.docs.map((doc) => RoomModel.fromForestore(doc)).toList());
      }
```

2. You can call inside `initState` or using `StreamBuilder` widget. I used `initState`

```dart
List<RoomModel> allRooms = [];
StreamSubscription roomSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var s4 = StreamGroup.merge([stream1(uid), stream2()]).asBroadcastStream();
    roomSubscription = s4.listen((event) {
      event.forEach((element) {
         if (element is RoomModel) {
            allRooms.removeWhere((e) => e.docId == element.docId);
            allRooms.add(element);
          }
      });
    });
  }
```

3. Dispose your stream

```dart
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    roomSubscription?.cancel();
  }
```

*I didn't test my answer. If you get any issues please comment down below.*

Comment: I tried using this code you suggested, and applied with StreamBuilder, it seems it is only able to retrieve public room

Comment: This should work. Is your return type equal?

Comment: Well, this is interesting, I simply changed the sequence of stream from ```[participantStream, publicRoomStream]``` to ```[publicRoomStream, participantStream]``` and is now return expected result, thank you so much to guide me here